# ALAssetsLibrary get Camera Roll

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I enumerate all assets groups using `ALAssetsLibrary`

Here is code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^enumerate)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (group == nil)
    {
        // enumerated all albums..
    }

    // I hot to check if group is Camera Roll ?

};

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:enumerate
                     failureBlock:nil];
```

How to check if some current enumerated is *CameraRoll*?

**Edit:** As i tested it was always the last, using this enumerating. But i am not sure if it is the rule, are there any references that i missed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get photos from camera roll use `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos` while enumerating assets library:

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                       usingBlock:enumerate
                     failureBlock:nil];
```

To detect what group you currently get:

```
if ([[group valueForProperty:@"ALAssetsGroupPropertyType"] intValue] == ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos)
{
    NSLog(@"Camera roll");
}
```

Comment: I saw about this solution, but i need to know which of my enumerated groups is camera roll, look at the code

Answer (score 3):

```
    imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray*mutableArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    ALAssetsLibrary*library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^enumerate)(ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
{
    if ([[group valueForProperty:@"ALAssetsGroupPropertyType"] intValue] == ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos)
    {
        NSLog(@"Camera roll");
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
            NSLog(@"Asset Name ----> %@",rep.filename);


        }];
    }
    // I hot to check if group is Camera Roll ?

};

 [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                       usingBlock:enumerate
                     failureBlock:nil];
```